# How can I add a normal distribution curve into geom_density?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a normal distribution curve in to my density curve to compare between them.

```
heights %>% filter(sex == "Male") %>% ggplot() +
  aes(x = height) +
  geom_density(fill = "blue")
```

What should I do after this?
I want it to be seen like this when it's done:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `stat_function`:

```
heights %>% filter(sex == "Male") %>% ggplot() +
  aes(x = height) +
  geom_density(fill = "blue") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 101, size = 1.5, args = list(mean = mean(heights$height[heights$sex == "Male"]), sd = sd(heights$height[heights$sex == "Male"])))
```

[image]